# Method of identification a filter. (low pass filter / high pass filter?)

Tags: image-processing, filter, signals, filtering, signal-processing

do you know how to identify a filter, when we know the mask? 
Is there any rule which says how to distinguish that is a high pass filter or low pass filter? the mask, for example:

```
1 0 -1; 
2 0 -2; 
1 0 -1;
```

Somebody told me to try test it with [ESF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_transfer_function_%28infrared_imaging%29#The_edge-spread_function) but I not sure.

I know that this filter is a high pass filter, I know that is a Sobel filter but how to determinate it when we have got different matrix?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about image and signal processing and would be better on [dsp](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement Fourier transform on the filter kernel and observe the magnitude in frequency domain (in Matlab it is `abs(fftshift(fft2(a)));`). The magnitude distribution of the sobel kernel is:

```
1.7321         0    1.7321
6.9282         0    6.9282
1.7321         0    1.7321
```

No value in the center (corresponding to low frequency components), so it's a high pass filter.

**EDIT**

Regarding the edge spread function method, you need to extract the edges from the original image first, and then,

```
e=edge(a);
esf=e(size(e,1)/2,:); %Take the centre line as a profile, e is the edge distributions in the image
lsf=gradient(esf); %The LSF is the derivative of the ESF
f=fft(lsf);
mtf=abs(f);
mtf=mtf(1:end/4); %Get rid of the double-ended spectrum and the long
```

Comment: Thx, but how to do it only with pen and paper? ;)
I saw some matrix of high pass filter and most of them have negatives numbers, is this a key to determine a filter?

Comment: it may not be true every time, but mostly given a filter kernel, if the maximum locates at the center while decreases towards all the directions, it is a low pass filter; while if the center values are very low and the values surrounding is higher, it may serve as a edge extractor, or high pass filter.

Comment: Another not-allways-true-rule is that if the sum of all components in the matrix is zero, the filter is high pass.